# How to remove a project (from the workspace) in PHPStorm?

Tags: ide, phpstorm, projects-and-solutions

How can I delete (and not simply close) a project in PHPStorm?

Comment: Delete from Recent Projects List ... or physically from the disk? If 2nd -- then it's not possible to do from IDE -- you have to do it manually using your file manager (Explorer/Finder/etc). If first -- press Delete button in v6 (or click on "x" in v5) when hovering over the project name in Recent Projects list when NO project is opened.

Comment: I thought, there would be something like workspaces like in eclipse. OK, thank you!

Comment: It looks like its "fn+delete" on hover for Phpstorm6

Comment: We can modify `.idea/modules.xml` file manually, if other options can't be reached

Answer (score 115):

**Two Approaches for PHPSTORM 2018.3 Version **

A. Eternal Removal or Deletion from Hardware and Phpstorm IDE

```
  Please visit the folder 'PhpstormProjects' and delete the project file manually. If you do so, you will see the folder disappear from Phpstorm explore window. This might be weird, but true.
```

B. Remove from the recent project panel of Phpstorm 2018.3
   (The folder after such removal will hide and a creation of the same name of project will restore the removed from the recent project panel.)

```
    1. Click  File > Close project 

    2. From Recent projects, select project, press the fn(on normal keyboard -       key between right Alt and Ctrl, not windows key)+Delete
```

Comment: On Windows 7/WebStorm 9, when you close the project and see the recent list, you can also hover your mouse over the project and hit the Backspace key and it will prompt you to delete it.

Comment: I didn't need to press Fn. Just Delete.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't click on the project (this opens it again), just hover your mouse over it and then press Delete or Backspace (just as Gordon, I didn't need to press Fn at the same time). I'm using PhpStorm 8 on Ubuntu 14.

Comment: Honestly, I do not think this is user-friendly.

Answer (score 28):

<kbd>Backspace</kbd> did the trick for me (Windows 7 + PHPStorm 7.1.3). You might want to try <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> as well.

Comment: FTW! Thanks, not sure why this is not marked as correct.

Comment: Approved on 2019.3.2 - Mac OS, Thanks !

Comment: On Windows it’s the Delete key (PHPStorm 2022.3.3)

Answer (score 13):

I know this post is a little old, but for MAC OS X phpStorm 6*, on the welcome to JetBrains PhpStorm page (under the recent projects use arrow keys up/down to select the project you want to remove, the hold the fn+delete.

Cheers

Comment: old FN+delete... how convenient. :s, anyway, thanks for sharing it.

Comment: It's the keyboard shortcut for deleting stuff in PhpStorm. It's the same for deleting files. Also, this is really old now…

Answer (score 11):

Follow this simple steps:

1. Just close project by using file menu.
2. Select project name from Recent Projects at left side panel by using up/down arrow keys.
3. Now just press Del key on keyboard.

Comment: Easiest way. Worked for me on mac.

Answer (score 8):

1. Click File > Close project
2. From Recent projects, select project, press the Fn + Delete on your keyboard

If you want delete a project entirely, delete the ".idea" folder within the project under Finder. This folder is hidden by default (i:e that's because it starts with a dot "." ). You will need to enable "View Hidden Files/Folders" in Finder

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because the .idea folder identifies a folder as a PhPStorm project folder. in Windows and Nix systems

Answer (score 6):

I had multiple projects opened in same window. 
Removed the one project by right click -> 'Remove from Project View'

It only removes from list, not from hard drive.

Comment: This answer is especially applicable to the latest version of PHP Storm 2018.3 which now lets you attach a project to an existing project when you open a project. If you need to then detach the project, this answer is how you achieve this.

Comment: their documentation says same. I have no such menu item. And I can't find that action with actions lookup (Mac OS PhpStorm 2020.1)

Answer (score 6):

For 2017/2018/2019/2020 versions, go to:

**File->Open Recent->Manage Projects...**

and click the **X** (that appears when hovering over an option) to delete it from the Projects list. This just removes the reference; it doesn't delete files from the disk.

Answer (score 6):

year 2019. PhpStorm v2018.3.5 - can't detach the project after attached. There's no "Close Project" in File menu, and no "Remove from Project View" in context menu as [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/opening-multiple-projects.html) says. Seems like a bug.

Just can't get rid of that extra project I've attached. Only one thing helped: removal of the `.idea` sub directory.

**important note:** it's about project **Attach** when you can't remove it from the Project view.

#### UPDATE/SOLVED:

Here's how to remove accidentally attached project from the current Project view:

1. `.idea/modules.xml`

you can either edit that file (remove that new/added entry, easy to find) or remove that entire file (don't worry, it will be re-created on restart).

2. Also it could've been added to `.idea/vcs.xml` (don't remove it, just find the corresponding `<mapping ...>` entry in it and remove, it's under `VscDirectoryMappings`)
3. Also it can be listed in `.idea/<projectname>.iml` file (find it in `module > component > orderEntry`, see `module-name` attribute), remove from there too.
4. restart the PhpStorm.

you will see no attached projects again.

I didn't find any UI options to do this (Mac OS Catalina, PhpStorm 2020.1, same on previous/older versions).

Comment: Have you tried to use the answer provided by jabbascript? That works perfectly for me, and "doesn't work" doesn't look like a legit answer to me then

Comment: @NicoHaase you mean removing the project from the recent list (Manage Projects)? Yes, I tried. It does nothing to attached project. Attached project is different - it's when you go "File -> Attach Project...". After that you will see another project in the Project tab. And it just can't be removed out of there

Comment: Thanks, that helped me … you missed something - the folder is .idea not idea ;)

Answer (score 3):

1. Select the project in project view
2. Edit -> Remove project from view

Alternatively hit Delete.

(Default Keymap Settings)

Comment: Thanks, this is the one I was looking for.

Comment: very strange. I saw that menu item, but only until I attach new project. Once attached - there's no such item anymore (to remove). Really weird =\

Comment: @Roman86 might it be due to you being on a Mac? Because I just used that option on my Win 10 PC PHPStorm 2023.1

Comment: @DarioFumagalli might be a case, thank you. I don't use this feature, and just hope that this issue was fixed )

Answer (score 2):

in phpStorm 7 on windows, selecting project/delete does delete the files erc but does NOT remove it from the "recent Projects" list. I found that highlighting it, then pressing Backspace is the key combination to remove it from the list! Maybe it has changed in v7.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently jetbrains can't decide on one way?

For me on Windows 7 highlighting the project and then windowkey + del did the trick

Answer (score 2):

In my PhpStorm 7.1 (OSx), there is a "Clear List" link in the menu, under 'File' > 'Open Recent' that clears your entire list.

Comment: The fact that one has to google the information to do somethin as trivial as that says a lot about the editor itself, doesn't it?

Comment: @rbaleksandar How much have you used phpStorm? It's really great, commit a few weeks to it and you'll see.

Comment: @rbaleksandar you are absolutely correct in what you are saying.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you cannot DELETE a project by pressing "delete" or "backspace" (or clicking the "x" in the upper right corner) in the recent projects list. These operations will only remove the project from being listed in the recent projects list.

You can check this out by looking at the project folders in the directory that WebStorm creates under your user name.

By the way I have WebStorm v.10 running on Win 7 x64 and none of the steps listed here by other users allow me to actually delete a project. The only way I have found out is manual.

This would work in at least Windows 7:

Navigate to the "WebstormProjects" directory under your Windows user name, and delete the project directory. This will remove it from the recent projects list the next time you launch WebStorm.